# calling function in tab.screen component causes app to crash locally

Tags: reactjs, react-native

On snack.expo my code works fine. However when I run it locally, the app immediately crashes. I have determined it is from the call to MyTabs in the home tabscreen. When you replace MyTabs with just Home, the app runs fine. However, for my overall project, I need the MyTabs function.

If anyone could provide some insight as to why that might be I would appreciate it more than you know! If I need to provide any details about my package.json file or anything else, please let me know.

Here is a [demo](https://snack.expo.dev/@priedejm/appjs-crashing) that runs the exact code I am talking about on snack.expo.

This is the [repository](https://github.com/priedejm/stackoverflow) I posted

Here is my app.js file

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";

import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";
import { MaterialCommunityIcons } from "@expo/vector-icons";

import Home from "./screens/Home";

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function MyTabs() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={Home}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator
        initialRouteName="Home"
        screenOptions={{
          tabBarActiveTintColor: "#F60081",
          tabBarInactiveTintColor: "#4d4d4d",
          tabBarStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#d1cfcf",
            borderTopColor: "transparent",
          },
        }}
      >
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={MyTabs}
          options={{
            tabBarLabel: "Home",
            headerShown: false,
            tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
              <MaterialCommunityIcons name="home" color={color} size={size} />
            ),
          }}
        />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator();
```

Comment: what do you mean by running it locally? did you mean making an apk then installing it on the device?

Comment: @MRPMOHIBURRAHMAN By locally I mean, creating an app expo init app and then running this code. I use the expo app to run it on my own device. I have confirmed it crashes on a separate device as well.

Comment: please add the error you get in your question

Comment: No error gets logged in the terminal or in the expo app. It simply just crashes

Comment: It'd be better if you share a repo instead of just the snack for us to give it a better look

Comment: Ill do that now. Thank you @diedu

Comment: @JustinPriede tell us wich device you are using, and also if u did try it on a simulator ??

Comment: I am using it on an iphone 11, no simulator. I am using it through the expo app. I have also tried an iphone X and an iphone 12 all through the expo app. I have received the same results for all. @diedu I just uploaded the repository that includes my node_modules folder. I took this folder from my overall project so there are probably some extraneous dependencies.

Comment: Also, thank you guys for the help. I appreciate it more than you know. I know this is not the place for "thank yous" but I just could not help myself.

Comment: Sorry, I don't use Mac, I'm not able to help you further. What I would recommend, though, is you debug the app with Xcode and see if the logs show any error, I can't give you the exact steps to do it since I only do android, but there should be a way

Comment: you might also want to add the `react-native-ios` tag to your post. I tried to add it but for some reason SO doesn't let me

Answer (score 0):

After installing the project locally, i got some warnings on npm.

to deal with that i did the following, which i suggest you to try :

1- delete `node_modules` using git bash `rm -r node_modules`

2- delete  `package-lock.json` file

3- clear cache : `npm cache clear --force`

4- install modules again `npm install`

And it worked perfectly.

[image]

If you are getting nothing on the console:
Build to your device using Xcode. Then select Window > Devices & Simulators from the menu. Select your device and open the device's console. You can get additional information by reading the console while as the app crashes. Hopefully that helps!

Comment: If this doesn't solve your problem, please consider sharing your console to find out what is the problem

Comment: Is this an iPhone? It seems the app crashes in iOS

Comment: @diedu it's an android, but if the app crashes on iOS you must get an error or something in your console, you don't??

Comment: @chikabala When I run the app locally through the expo app, I do not get a error at all in the terminal or in the app. It simply just crashes. Using xcode might help though, I need a mac.

Comment: @JustinPriede yeah that will help, meanwhile you can try to create another project and export all your screens to it, and run the new project (i usually solve react native problems like that), best of luck

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried changing the name props on Tab.Navigator for component MyTabs to `MyTabs` instead of `Home` ?

Comment: yes, unfortunately that does not impact anything. It still crashes.

Comment: Thank you for checking it out though, I appreciate it more than you know.